# adding tuple to new object instance field

Tags: c#, switch-statement, tuples

I'm attempting to run a function that passes and returns a `Measurement` object. Within the `Measurement` object, I have a variable `volume` which is a tuple and takes both a decimal and an enum called `VolumeUnits` which contains a range of liquid measurement types.

```
 public Measurement ConvertVolumeUnit(Measurement measure)
    {
        Measurement.VolumeUnits newUnit;
        decimal size = measure.volume.Item1;


        switch (measure.volume.Item2)
        {
            case Measurement.VolumeUnits.tsp:
                if (measure.volume.Item1 > 3)
                {
                    size = size / 3;
                    goto case Measurement.VolumeUnits.Tbsp;
                }
                else
                {
                    newUnit = Measurement.VolumeUnits.tsp;
                    break;
```

The function runs a switch that converts my units, but I am not sure how to establish a new `Measurement` instance and create a new `Measurement.volume` item to return the newly converted tuple.

```
             case Measurement.VolumeUnits.gal:
                 newUnit = Measurement.VolumeUnits.gal;
                 break;
             default:
                 break;
         }

         Measurement newMeasure = new Measurement();
         newMeasure.volume = Tuple.Create(size, newUnit);
```

Essentially, I want to return `newMeasure` but I have to fill that `volume` tuple first. My error is telling that newUnit is unassigned. Is this just because the `default` does not assign a value to `newUnit`?

Answer (score 0):

After writing this all out it would appear that newUnit indeed must be assigned in the default section or initially to avoid this error.

Comment: Pretty much. What happens when `measure.volume.Item2` isn't `tsp` or `gal`? Even if you cover all values currently defined in the `VolumeUnits` enum, you can still use values outside the declared range. For example: `Measurement.VolumeUnits someUndefinedUnit = (Measurement.VolumeUnits)9999;` is valid, executable code. The compiler recognizes that there is a _possible_ code path in which `newUnit` has not been assigned a value.